# Load balancing: Is there a way to tell from the client side, which server is currently being targeted by the load balancer?

Tags: web, load-balancing

We have a load balanced website. It connects to 6 different servers. Is there any way (ping or otherwise) to determine from the client side, which server the load is being passed to by the load balancer?

Comment: This question does not make much sense unless you are implementing stickiness in your LB strategy.

Comment: It's handy for debugging i.e. if some requests don't always behave the  same. I've had issues where replication failed across servers so they weren't quite configured the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research Ive realized that you can get some information like the web server IIS version etc by looking at the HTTP header response. But you cannot tell from the client end which server this response originated from. Long story short, what is behind the load balancer is opaque to the user at the client end.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a cookie that contains this information.

Comment: Or a HTTP header as cookies impact (slightly) on other requests to the same hostname, not that there's that much in it!